# Angular + firebase: .then() not working when calling function from a service file

Tags: angular, firebase, promise

I have a function inside my `QuestionService` file:

```js
  updateQuestion(question: Question){

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>{
      this.db.database.ref(`questions/${question.key}`)
          .update(question)
  });
}
```

However, when called from within my `questions.component.ts` file with a `.then()` at the end, the `.then()` does not get executed:

```js
          this.questionsService.updateQuestion(this.question).then(res =>{
            console.log('success editing the question') //not being logged
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Question Updated', life: 3000});
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Error', detail:'There has been an error'})
        })
```

Mind that if I add a `.then()` inside my `service` file, it will be executed normally:

```js
  updateQuestion(question: Question){

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>{
      this.db.database.ref(`questions/${question.key}`)
          .update(question)
          .then(res => {
            console.log('question was updated'); //is logged
          }, err => {
            reject(err)
          });
  });
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea why that might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version of `updateQuestion()`, neither `resolve` nor `reject` is called, therefore the returned Promise is guaranteed to remain pending - it will never settle.

The second version isn't right either. `reject` appears in the code but `resolve` doesn't, meaning the returned Promsie can only ever settle on its error path (or will remain pending).

The solution is simple; purge the `new Promise()` wrapper and simply return the Promise returned by `this.db.database.ref().update()`.

```
updateQuestion(question: Question) {
    return this.db.database.ref(`questions/${question.key}`).update(question);
}
```

Now, providing `this.db.database.ref().update()` is written correctly, the returned Promise will settle on its succes path or error path depending on how the update goes:

```
this.questionsService.updateQuestion(this.question)
.then(res => {
    // success path (update succeeded)
    this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Question Updated', life: 3000});
}).catch(error => {
    // error path (update failed)
    this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Error', detail:'There has been an error'});
    // alternatively
    // this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Error', detail:error.message});
});
```